# Upload file with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Normally to upload files using selenium must find the upload textbox, but in this site:

https://www.ofoct.com/audio-converter/audio-to-text.html

There is no input to use for uploading, how to upload files with selenium on this site? I use python and the gecko driver on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that there is no input for file uploading?

Here it is:
[image]

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("/path/to/file.mp3")
```

works fine for me